# Getting the `#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME` value in an org-buffer

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to retrieve the value of the `#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME`property in an `org-mode` buffer using Emacs Lisp in order to automate some calls of `(shell-command "foo %s" export_file_name)`.

Is there a function that returns this value directly? I guess so, since it is used in all `org-mode` export backends. But I've just spent a lot of time going through the documentation and I can't find anything satisfactory (or that works properly).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: OK thank you @Drew, it seems this question does not really fit the standard of the tag. sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are somewhere on the line with

```
#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME: foo/bar
```

then the following form:

```
(org-element-property :value (org-element-at-point))
```

will return `foo/bar`. But you have to be on that line (or after it with nothing intervening). That's why the code in `ox.el` does the following:

```el
    ;; Check #+EXPORT_FILE_NAME keyword.
    (org-with-point-at (point-min)
       (catch :found
         (let ((case-fold-search t))
           (while (re-search-forward
               "^[ \t]*#\\+EXPORT_FILE_NAME:[ \t]+\\S-" nil t)
             (let ((element (org-element-at-point)))
               (when (eq 'keyword (org-element-type element))
                 (throw :found
                   (org-element-property :value element))))))))
```

It goes to the beginning of the buffer and searches (case-insensitively) for an `#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` line; it then parses the current element to make sure that it is at a keyword line (and e.g. not in some comment that happens to include the string it searched for) and, if so, retrieves and returns the value of the property. N.B. it retrieves the *first* instance of such a line - if you have more than one, the rest are ignored.

Even though there *is* [some documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) on this, it's the kind of thing that an example in well-written code makes much clearer than any documentation. That's one of the reasons that FLOSS as a programming methodology is superior to any other.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thank you very much,
I had imagined as a last resort to try to rewrite such a function but I'm not yet sufficiently versed in elisp for that...  I will therefore study this portion of the code in detail and adapt it to my needs.
Indeed, we should all be able to configure our work tool as we wish. This requires an apprenticeship, but what craftsman has not learned how to maintain and adapt his tools? That's why I like emacs and FLOSS programming in general.